# Import error: Flask not resolved in Python test with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask

I do not understand why it shows that the flask is not imported. I checked my terminal and it says that is has been. What am I doing wrong? [this is what I am trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naJN2.png)[this is me chekcing my flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1BLQ.png)

I am trying to run my test, but the flask keeps giving me the message: Import "flask" could not be resolved

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), format the code into your question instead.

Comment: Likely you have two different versions of python installed on your computer.  Flask was installed for the version of python in "the terminal" (whatever that is), but VS Code is using a different version, where Flask is not installed.

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two possible causes of this issue.

1. You didn't install the flask package. The solution is that you can run command `pip install flask` in the terminal.
2. You chosen an incorrect python interpreter which didn't exist the `flask`. You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct python environment.